# Displaying image that was sent through ASIHTTPRequest in a web browser

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, web-services, asihttprequest

I am using `ASIHTTPRequest` to upload an image to a `webservice`. my code works fine (i think), but i am not sure how to write the web service so i could retrieve the image and display it (in a `web browser`).

i don't know if this is relevant but i'm passing the image data from the iPhone. so the `web service` now will have to take this `image data` and convert it to a `PNG` and display it on the `web browser`.

I have no clue how to do this. Can someone help me out with a tutorial or sample code to begin with.

note: in `ASIHTTPRequest` i used the method `postData` to send the data to the `web service`
and the `web services` are supposed to be written in `PHP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ASIFormDataRequest, it has a method for file uploads (addFile), then you just work off the $_FILES superglobal in PHP as you would with a regular HTML form upload. On the iPhone side you're best off saving the image to the Documents or Cache folder for your application and referencing the filepath in the request.

Something like this:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url/path"]];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request addFile:filePath forKey:@"uploaded"];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(onUploadDone:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(onUploadError:)];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but i have to send the image once i have had taken the picture (using the camera) or from UIImagePickerController (selecting from the library). I can't use a url as shown in your example (http://www.example.com/image.jpg)

Comment: Objective C uses "URLs" both as a reference to web urls and to the local file system. In my code example filePath is an NSUrl of a local file saved from the camera. When you get the image object save to the filesystem using [data writeToURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] atomically:YES] (data being an NSData representation of your image)